# Is there a way to verify if a topic as been subscribed to

Tags: python, mqtt, subscription, paho

I am trying to make a python program that receive and send messages to my mqtt server from many devices (gateway). What i would like to do is when i receive a message from a device, verify if this device adresse as already been subscribed so i can receive external message to this device and route it to this particular device.

Right now each time i receive data from a device i resubscribe to the topic not knowing if it is already subscribed.

```
if (time.time() - last_sent_message) >= 0.25:
    message = daemon.memcache_read()
    if message:
        daemon.serial_print(message)
        #daemon.udp_send(message)
        try:
            mqttc.publish("to_" + message[8:17], message)
            mqttc.subscribe("from_" + message[8:17], 0)
        except:
            pass
        last_sent_message = time.time()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is up to you to keep track of what topics you have subscribed to